# Why this equation does not develop a boundary layer?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

The equation I am talking about is
$$
\epsilon  y''(x)+y(x)+1=0,y(0)=0,y(1)=1
$$

The $+1$ is not essential as $y(x)$ can be decomposed into $1 + y_1$, but is kept here for a more direct comparison with the other example below. This equation takes a more innocent look if multiplied by $1/\epsilon $ that yields $y''(x) + 1/ \epsilon  y(x) + 1/\epsilon = 0$, sine/cosine function follows (the figure below shows solution with $\epsilon $ = 0.01, which corresponds to a period $2 \pi \sqrt{\epsilon} = 0.62$).

[image: Solution for equation 1]

Some may say as $\epsilon $ decreases, the frequency gets higher and the curve get steeper, but there is no boundary layer for at least two reasons: first, this is a global behavior; second, typical boundary layers has an exponential rate of change that limit it to a narraw region (then merges smoothly with the outer solution). The example to be compared against is one with the second term $y(x)$ replaced by $y'(x)$, clearly boundary layer develops (figure also uses $\epsilon = 0.01$). 
[image: Solution for equation 2]

Buy why? The only distinction is there is no first order term in the first equation, but this argument appears to be very superficial.

Comment: As a guess, because the order drops by 2 for $ϵ=0$. Set the boundary condition to $y(1)=2$ to make a solution even more impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a global breakdown in your solution here, which means a normal boundary layer expansion wont work, because the solution is rapidly varying for all $x$. If you do a boundary layer scaling you get $y''+y+1=0$, which is valid anywhere. So you can't use use boundary layer theory, and have to use WKB theory. The WKB expansion is
$$ y(x)=\exp\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\delta^nS_n(x)\right), $$
where $\delta$ is a small parameter that we will have to pick later. Then, find it's second derivative,
$$ y''(x)=\left[\frac{1}{\delta^2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\delta^nS_n'(x)\right)^2+\frac{1}{\delta}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\delta^nS_n''(x)\right]\exp\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\delta^nS_n(x)\right). $$
Now, as you noted, you can write your equation as $\epsilon Y''(x)=-Y(x)$, ($Y(x)=y(x)+1$) and I'll use that form too, it's much easier to work with. Substituting the expansions in, and removing the exponential terms, gives
$$ \frac{\epsilon}{\delta^2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\delta^nS_n'(x)\right)^2+\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\delta^nS_n''(x)=1. $$
Now we have to pick the scale of $\delta$. Using dominant balance, it shouldn't be too hard to see that we require $\delta^2=\epsilon$ so that the largest term on the left balance the right of the equation. If you substitute $\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon}$, and expand the equations in powers of $\sqrt{\epsilon}$, the first two equations are,
$$S_0'^2=-1$$
and
$$2S_0'S_1'+S_0''=0.$$

The solution to the first equation is 
$$S_0=Aix-Bix,$$
and the second equation is solved simply as,
$$S_1=C.$$

Putting these first two approximations back into the expansion for $y$ gives
$$Y=\exp\left(Aix/\sqrt{\epsilon}-Bix/\sqrt{\epsilon}+C\right)=A^*\sin\left(x/\sqrt{\epsilon}\right)+B^*\cos\left(x/\sqrt{\epsilon}\right) $$
and the boundary conditions (I'm using $Y(0)=1$, $Y(1)=1+k$, equivalent to $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=k$) give
$$Y=\cos\left(x/\sqrt{\epsilon}\right)+\frac{1+k-\cos\left(1/\sqrt{\epsilon}\right)}{\sin\left(1/\sqrt{\epsilon}\right)}\sin\left(x/\sqrt{\epsilon}\right).$$

Going back to your equation for $y(x)$, this is
$$y=\cos\left(x/\sqrt{\epsilon}\right)+\frac{1+k-\cos\left(1/\sqrt{\epsilon}\right)}{\sin\left(1/\sqrt{\epsilon}\right)}\sin\left(x/\sqrt{\epsilon}\right)-1.$$

It turns out that this is the exact solution to the equation. This is because if you write the equations as $\epsilon y''+Q(x)y=0$, $Q(x)=1$. The eikonal equation in general is 
$$S_0'^2=-Q(x),$$
which has solutions
$$S_0(x)=\pm\int^x\sqrt{Q(t)}\mathrm dt$$
and correspondingly,
$$S_1(x)=-\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(Q(x)\right).$$
In this case, $\ln\left(Q(x)\right)=0$ of course, and so all the higher order equations have only the trivial solution.

A great reference for this is Bender and Orszag's book "Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers".

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your answer, I will need a few days before making further response.

Comment: Actually, for this example, WKB theory is overkill because the equation is linear. That is also why just doing a boundary layer type re-scaling as in Frits' answer is adequate. I'm not sure whether it is coincidence or to be expected that the solution of the re-scaled equation is able to match both boundary conditions.

Comment: Hi David, what's the role of Eikonal equation here? Is it just a usual way to call the first step of the WKB method?

Comment: Yes, it's just the name for that equation in WKB theory, it's doesn't mean anything else (that I'm aware of).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is to use your observation that the oscillation frequency will increase as $\epsilon$ gets smaller. Therefore, it seems useful to introduce the rescaled variable
\begin{equation}
\xi = \frac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon}},
\end{equation}
such that the ODE becomes
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d}^2 y}{\text{d}\xi^2} + y(\xi) +1 = 0,\; y(0) = 0, \;y(1/\sqrt{\epsilon}) = 1. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
In this 'desingularised' formulation, you see that the small parameter $\epsilon$ has vanished from the differential equation. It now only appears in the second boundary condition, which is now asymptotically 'far away', because we introduced the small scale variable $\xi$.

The solution to $(1)$ only including the boundary condition at $\xi=x=0$ is
\begin{equation}
 y(\xi) + 1 = \cos \xi + c_0 \sin \xi
\end{equation}
The second boundary condition now yields
\begin{equation}
 c_0  = \frac{2-\cos \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}}{\sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}}. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
As you can see, the problem $(1)$ has *no* solution if
\begin{equation}
 \epsilon = \epsilon_n := \frac{1}{4 \pi^2 n^2},
\end{equation}
because then every solution for which $y(0) = 0$ automatically satisfies $y(1) = 0$. Also, since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are periodic and bounded, $(2)$ does not have an asymptotic approximation for small values of $\epsilon$.

To answer your original question: not every singularly perturbed problem has a boundary layer. The appearance of the exact or approximate solution highly depends on the specific characteristics of the problem. A general approach to these questions is *geometric singular perturbation theory*, which combines methods from dynamical systems and multiple time scale analysis. For more information, see

C. Kuehn, *Multiple Time Scale Dynamics*, Springer, 2015.

Comment: +1 very nice answer. Actually, if you do dominant balance on the original ODE, the scaling $\epsilon^{-1/2}$ comes straight out, no intuition needed!

Comment: Good observation! It's always good to have an alternative to an 'intuitive' approach.